# Spring MVC - NoSuchMethodError exception - Tomcat7

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7, pom.xml

My maven project uses spring mvc. I get `no such method error`. I believe it is due to some conflict in version in dependencies but I do have all the dependencies of same version. The build is successful, but the tomcat throws the following exception:

`NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter`

Please give an idea of how to resolve the below error.

The below is pom.xml file.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> -->




    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<properties>
    <spring3.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring3.version>
    <jersey.version>2.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
</properties>
    <build>
    <finalName>ape</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
             </configuration>
     </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-istack-commons-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: "no such method error" always indicates that (1) your classpath is missing some libraries, or, (2) you did not recompile all your classes after you made changes. Edit: or, (2b) you have collected classes of different versions that won't work together.

Comment: Just noticed you got 3.1.0 of all packages from spring except the core package. This method you are not finding is in the one package with version 3.1.2. Does it exist there? Removed?

Comment: mattias: I removed that version 3.1.2

Comment: I didn't see the open tag `dependencies`. Missing it?